# Using async await with `useSelector` in React hooks

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios

I have a functional component that that has an input field where the user types a question and hits enter and I send the query to the backend.

Here is the simplified version of the functional component

**UserQuery.js**

```
import {postQuery} from '../actions/postQueryAction'

const UserQuery = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState("")

    function sendMessage(userQuery) {
            postUserQuery(userQuery)
    }


   return (
       <>
            <input 
                type="text" 
                value={name}
                onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
                onKeyPress={sendMessage}
                id="userQuery"
            />
       </>
   )

}

export default UserQuery
```

As you can see I have a callback called `postQuery` which actually makes the axios request and posts the user query. Here is how it looks like

**postQueryAction.js**

```
export const postQuery = (userQuery) => async dispatch => { 

    let userInfo = useSelector(state => state.userInfo.data)

    const username = userInfo.username
    const group = userInfo.group

    const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    }

    const params = {
        group: group,
        user: username, 
        data: userQuery

    }

    await axios.post(`/postQuestion`,params, {headers}, {
            
    }).then(response => {
        console.log("response check", response.data);

    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("Error log", err);

    });

}
```

But I get `Invalid hook call` error. If I remove `useSelector` code, then it doesn't complain and the request goes through.

I could use the `useSelector` in original functional component (**UserQuery.js**) and pass the parameters accordingly. But I want the `postQuery` method to only accept the `userQuery` parameter and figure the other information from the redux state.

What should I do?

Comment: Hey Ray, did my answer help you? I'm happy to look for another approach if that one didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hooks can only be called from [react components or other hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions). Instead of using the hook inside the `postQuery` function you could call it in the component and pass the user info to `postQuery`

```
const UserQuery = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  let userInfo = useSelector((state) => state.userInfo.data);
  function sendMessage(userQuery) {
    postUserQuery(userQuery, userInfo);
  }
...

export const postQuery = (userQuery, userInfo) => async (dispatch) => {
...
```

Comment: hey sorry. I was travelling and didn't get time to login to stack overflow. Yes I used an approach similar to yours and it stopped throwing errors although I am still working on it. But you pointed me in right direction. Thanks..